# Converting Python 3.6.5 List to a table

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently working on a project and I need help on converting a list to a table. I have figured it out one way but there has to be a shorter and a cleaner way of doing it and I am having a trouble figuring that out. My coding is the following (the part that I need help is at the bottom in **)

```
def main():

# Create a list for the sales person    
    sales_persons_list = inputSalesPeople()
    sales_amounts_list = inputSalesAmounts(sales_persons_list)
    displaySalesReport(sales_persons_list, sales_amounts_list)

# Create a list for the sales person
def inputSalesPeople():
    sales_persons_list = []
    count = 0
    while count < 5:
        Name = input("What is the name of the sales person?: ")
        count += 1
        sales_persons_list.append(Name)
    print(sales_persons_list)

    return sales_persons_list

def inputSalesAmounts(sales_persons_list):
    sales_amounts_list = []
    index = 0
    while index < len(sales_persons_list):
        Sales =float(input("How much did " + str(sales_persons_list[index]) + " make in sales?: $"))
        index += 1
        sales_amounts_list.append(Sales)
    print(sales_amounts_list)    

    return sales_amounts_list 

**def displaySalesReport(sales_persons_list, sales_amounts_list):
    Total_Sales = sum(sales_amounts_list)
    print("%-15s %-15s" %("Salespeople","Sales Amount"))
    print("%-15s %-15s" %(sales_persons_list[0],sales_amounts_list[0]))
    print("%-15s %-15s" %(sales_persons_list[1],sales_amounts_list[1]))
    print("%-15s %-15s" %(sales_persons_list[2],sales_amounts_list[2]))
    print("%-15s %-15s" %(sales_persons_list[3],sales_amounts_list[3]))
    print("%-15s %-15s" %(sales_persons_list[4],sales_amounts_list[4]))
    print()
    print("%-15s %-15s" %("Totals", Total_Sales))**

main()
```

This will display a correct table with correct value but as you can see it is kind of long and not clean. How can I shorten it? Thank you for the help!

Comment: What's wrong with a for loop?

Comment: You may want to check https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for this kind of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code output equals your code output :)

```
sales_persons_list = [input('What is the name of the sales person?: ') for i in range(5)]
print(sales_persons_list)
sales_amounts_list = [
    float(input('How much did {} make in sales?:'.format(sales_persons_list[i]))) for i in range(len(sales_persons_list))]
print(sales_amounts_list)
print("%-15s %-15s" %("Salespeople","Sales Amount"))
for i in range(len(sales_amounts_list)):
    print("%-15s %-15s" %(sales_persons_list[i],sales_amounts_list[i]))
print("%-15s %-15s" %("Totals", sum(sales_amounts_list)))
```

show list as table code:

```
print("%-15s %-15s" %("Salespeople","Sales Amount"))
for i in range(len(sales_amounts_list)):
    print("%-15s %-15s"%(sales_persons_list[i],sales_amounts_list[i]))
print("%-15s %-15s" %("Totals", sum(sales_amounts_list)))
```

## output

```
Salespeople     Sales Amount
a               1222.0
aa              1111.0
aaa             2222.0
aaaaa           3333.0
aaaaaa          1133.0
Totals          9021.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def displaySalesReport(sales_persons_list, sales_amounts_list):
    Total_Sales = sum(sales_amounts_list)
    print("%-15s %-15s" %("Salespeople","Sales Amount"))
    for s_person, s_amount in zip(sales_persons_list, sales_amounts_list):
        print("%-15s %-15s" % (s_person, s_amount))
    print("%-15s %-15s" %("Totals", Total_Sales))
```

This is a simplified version of your code, you could also use Python Pandas to create a table, Pandas is the best for data in tabular form but it provides much more than you need:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Salespeople': sales_persons_list, 'Sales Amount': sales_amounts_list}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df.append({'Sales Amount': Total}, index="Total")
print(df)
```

My code is pseudo you have to modify it to fit your need.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use one of many popular packages available to print tabular o/p. My suggestion is to use `tabulate`

```
from tabulate import tabulate
sales_persons_list = list('ABCDE')
sales_amounts_list = list('12345')
print (tabulate(zip(sales_persons_list, sales_amounts_list), tablefmt="plain"))
```

**Output**

```
A  1
B  2
C  3
D  4
E  5
```